# How do I nest a wordpress function inside another wordpress function?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, nested

I'm working on a wordpress theme and I'm trying to call the parent category's name to pull the appropriate page template.

I can get the call function to echo the correct name, but when I try to nest it the function doesn't run. I saw that I needed to use { } since I was already inside php but it still isn't working right. Can someone straighten me out?

This gives the correct output:

```
<?php $category = get_the_category();
$parent = get_cat_name($category[0]->category_parent);
if (!empty($parent)) {
echo '' . $parent;
} else {
echo '' . $category[0]->cat_name;
}
?>
```

. . . so I created a category_parent.php file with that in it.

This is what I'm trying to nest it in:

```
<?php get_template_part( ' ' ); ?>
```

Like this:

1.

```
<?php get_template_part( '<?php get_template_part( 'category_parent' ); ?>' ); ?>
```

or this

2.

```
<?php get_template_part( '{get_template_part( 'category_parent' ); }' ); ?>
```

Neither one works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know if this is what you want as I did not try to make sense of what you are doing. However, generally speaking, you do this:

```
<?php get_template_part( get_template_part( 'category_parent' ) ); ?>
```

Edit:

I looked up what `get_template_part()` does in WP, and I think Felix Kling's answer is what you need. There is a big difference between sending something to the screen and assigning it to a variable.

```
<?php
  echo 'filename';
?>
```

If you include that file, you will see `filename` in the browser. PHP knows nothing about it. (Okay, it could if you made use of output buffering functions, but that's besides the point...)

However if you do something like:

```
<?php
   $x = 'filename';
?>
```

You can now use it in your function:

```
<?php
  get_template_part($x);
?>
```

So what Felix is telling you to do is to put the logic that you currently have into a function. In this example:

```
<?php
  function foo()
  {
    return 'filename';
  }

  get_template_part(foo());
?>
```

Now whatever value `foo()` returns will be sent to your `get_template_part()`.

Taking your code:

```
$category = get_the_category();
$parent = get_cat_name($category[0]->category_parent);
if (!empty($parent)) {
  $name = $parent;
} else {
  $name = $category[0]->cat_name;
}

get_template_part($name);
```

You could take Felix's answer and put it into a file called `category_parent.php`, and then use it like:

```
require_once 'category_parent.php'
get_template_part(getName());
```

Comment: the 'category_parent' part is still dead in that instance. it tries to find "category_parent.php" instead of finding "categoryname.php"

Comment: Maybe I am asking the wrong question? I want the category parent script called and the answer to be part of the other get_template_part

Comment: Ah! Thank you all for the help! I didn't realize that the echo was only giving me a screen output.

I am working on a wordpress template that calls certain content / layouts/ styles based on the category. Unfortunately, if I created a subcategory it would require a new layout which defeats the purpose of being able to apply it to the category. This lets me call the style based on the parent category so I only have to write two or three pages and they are automatically applied to the right post-type.

Everything works now :)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I am not so familiar with Wordpress, but it seems to me, you could do:

```
function getName() {
    $category = get_the_category();
    $parent = get_cat_name($category[0]->category_parent);
    if (!empty($parent)) {
        return '' . $parent;
    } else {
        return '' . $category[0]->cat_name;
    }
}

get_template_part(getName());
```

Comment: Thanks, that part was returning the right answer, I was only including it in case that was causing something else to not work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

konforce is correct about the syntax and, like konforce, I have no idea what you are trying to do. You do not need to use { } because your are not trying to dynamically name a variable and you certainly don't need to escape to php using `<?php ?>`, as (1) you are already in php and (2) it will stop interpreting PHP and assume html the second it hits the first '?>'.

There is no special syntax for nesting functions. Simply:

```
get_template_part(get_template_part('category_parent'));
```

is the syntax, but I have no idea what the function is or does, so I have no idea if that will work.

To debug, why don't you try this:

```
$parent = get_template_part('category_parent');
echo 'parent: ' . $parent . '<br />';
$result = get_template_part($parent);
echo 'result: ' . $result . '<br />';
```

Answer (score -1):

When using variables in php strings, you will need to use double quotes ("). I assume option 2 should work then.

Comment: like this? <?php get_template_part( "{get_template_part( 'category_parent' ); }" ); ?> It still "kills" any code within the quotes so that doesn't run.

Comment: Sorry, I never tried it for functions, so wasn't sure whether that would work or not, but seems it won't :)